# Update IAM policy for S3 bucket using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

We have a use case: Update the IAM policy as new bucket is created.

New bucket is created using cloudformation template.

Is it possible to update the current IAM policy e.g. add a new Resource value using cloudformation ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the SNS topic to your cloudformation, the cloudformation will publish to the SNS topic. Configure the SNS to invoke the Lambda function that will update your IAM policy.

Provide the required permissions to your

CloudFormation -> to send notification to SNS

SNS -> to Invoke your lambda

Lambda Function -> To Update IAM Policy

Comment: I am trying to create the SNS notification when a new S3 bucket is created , sequence you provided I think will work only on existing resources.

Use case we have is : Create a new S3 bucket and invoke Lambda function to add new bucket as a new resource

Comment: As you have mentioned CloudFormation will create S3 Bucket. CloudFormation will publish to the SNS and it will invoke the lambda function, in Lambda you have to Check for the CloudFormation Event for S3 Bucket or check from the CloudFormation Resources Created after describing CloudFormation, when you find S3 Bucket is in Create Complete, then update the IAM Policy

Comment: Thanks problem I am facing is how to publish to SNS for S3 bucket creation ? I do not see an event specified for bucket creation as part of cloud formation TopicConfigurations > Event

Comment: CloudFormation doesnot provide events specific to the resources, it will send generalize notification, you have to check in your lambda function about the S3 bucket create complete status.

Comment: Alternative, use CloudFormation CustomResource for Bucket Creation and set the IAM policy in the same Lambda function, instead of S3 Bucket Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a group or role that will have access to all of the S3 buckets, then create a new IAM policy for each S3 bucket and assign to the group or role using the `Groups` or `Roles` properties of the `AWS::IAM::Policy` resource.